# Login and register on the same page ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have both login forms and register forms on the same page.

I have the following code:

```
@model MusicRank.Models.AuthenticationModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log In";
}

<h2>Log In</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (@Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Auth", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginModel.Email)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginModel.Password)
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </p>
}


<h2>Register</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Auth", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Password)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Country)

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </p>
}
```

As u can see, I have to models to work with here. AuthenticationModel looks like this:

```
public class AuthenticationModel
{
    public LogInModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to register and hit submit, the values that are passed to my Register-action are NULL. I can't understand why..

Here Is my Register-action:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            var user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Country = model.Country
            };

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignIn(user);
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: wheres the controller code yo? I'm guessing youre forgetting [FromBody]

Comment: @ScottSelby: Check my updated question

Comment: Also, Inspect your input fields if they have the same name as the one's you are submitting.

Comment: @HastaPasta: The name of my Regsiter-fields are for example: RegisterModel.Email

Comment: But your RegisterModel expects Email As default model binders magically does all the type conversion and mapping of all these values to the Model properties

Comment: It's just that the RegisterModel in the view does not match your RegisterModel in the controller action. As the RegisterModel is inside a AuthenticationModel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy Solution is to match the model properties by yourself

Do This

```
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
```

Remove This as

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Email)
```

Converts to

```
 <input type="text" name="RegisterModel.Email" id="RegisterModel.Email" />
```

Which the default model binder cant match it to your proper fields

Answer (score 3):

The actual issue is that you're using AuthenticationModel in the view and accepting RegistreModel in the action. You should accept AuthenticationModel in the action and the RegisterModel property will be populated.

If you make this change you can continue to use EditorFor which is better practice.